# How to get back a Size from a 2d object array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, 2d

I declare a 2d array.

```
object[,] tbl = 
{
                { new Size(140,112), new Point(20,20) },
                { new Size(140,112), new Point(160,20) }
            
};
```

I am looping through the array

```
for(int i=0; i < tbl.GetLength(0); i++)
{

}
```

How do I get back the Size and Point within the loop?

Comment: What situation led you to need to put `Size` and `Point` in the same array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Size size = (Size)tbl[i, 0];
Point point = (Point)tbl[i, 1];
```

But it's better not to use `object` like this because of all the casts. Create your own class with a `Size` and `Point` property, or use a `Tuple<Size, Point>`.